# Проблема с циклом google apps script

Tags: javascript, for, google-apps-script

**Есть вот такая часть кода**

var ss = tabl.getRange(2,1).getValue();

for(;ss==“”;){logger.log(“good”)}

Значение  переменной ss перед циклом равно пустоте и поэтому когда доходит до цикла, он запускается и работает, но когда я вношу изменения в строку, то есть уже ss не равно пустоте цикл все равно продолжает работать и выдавать в журнал «good”. А мне нужно чтобы после того как строка уже не является  пустой выполнение цикла закончилось

Answer (score 1):

Ваше утверждение о состоянии функции и ее переменных неверны, т.к.

```
function fn() {
  let ss = '';
  let i = 0;

  for (; ss === '';) {
    console.log(++i);
    if (i > 5) ss = '?';
  }

  console.log(ss);
}
```

```
Execution log
2:34:17 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:34:17 PM  Info    1
2:34:17 PM  Info    2
2:34:17 PM  Info    3
2:34:17 PM  Info    4
2:34:17 PM  Info    5
2:34:17 PM  Info    6
2:34:17 PM  Info    ?
2:34:17 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Не думаю, что в Rhino будет работать как-то по-другому чем в V8.

Что касается вашего вопроса, вам в цикле нужно проверять не обновилось ли значение в ячейке

```
function myFunction() {
  const book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const range = book
    .getSheetByName('Тестовая')
    .getRange('A1');
  let value = getValue(range);
  for (; value === '';) {
    console.log(value);
    book.toast('Ожидаются данные в ячейке A1');
    Utilities.sleep(900);
    value = getValue(range);
  }
  book.toast(`Значение в ячейке A1 "${value}"`);
  console.log(value);
}

/**
 * @param {globalThis.SpreadsheetApp.Range} range
 */
const getValue = (range) => {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return range.getValue();
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Запуск')
    .addItem('Запустить пример', 'myFunction')
    .addToUi();
}
```

- Полный пример в Таблице https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17l7JNqDg9FSyXirvF-GgNcm1GMnH_C239TfgxHgrMv0/edit?usp=sharing
- Видео работы примера https://t.me/contributor_pw_chat/5862

Comment: Так я не понял в чем моя ошибка??

Comment: Не в том, что вы описали. Этот подход работает ожидаемо.

Comment: Ну я Вам говорю как есть. В google script, в таблицах я получаю значение строки с помощью getRange (оно пустое) и в цикле задаю тоже пустоту и он начинает работать, но как только  я меняю значение в самой таблице в строке где я получаю изначально пустоту на какое-то значение то цикл не прерывается, он продолжает считать, что там пустота. А когда я делаю for( var i=0; i<5;i++){….} все работает как положено счетчик доходит до 4 и останавливается. В чем проблема у меня может быть?

Comment: Пришлите больше данных. Ваш пример, пока работает без ошибок. Пришлите Таблицу с проектом.

Comment: А можно Вам куда-то бросить? На email или что-то в этом роде?

Comment: Поищите по нику в сети - найдете.

Comment: Нашел. Спасибо. Я Вам в телеграмм сброшу

Comment: Вопрос все еще открыт.. нужна помощь

Answer (score 0):

возможно нужно обновить после изменения в ячейке  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).